# Reversal of a singly-linked list in Rust

Tags: linked-list, rust

I was trying to write some simple data structures to practice ownership concepts in Rust:

```
type Link<T> = Option<Box<Node<T>>>;

struct Node<T> {
    elem: T,
    next: Link<T>,
}

struct List<T> {
    head: Link<T>,
}

pub struct Iter<'a, T: 'a> {
    next: Option<&'a Node<T>>,
}

impl<T> List<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        List { head: None }
    }

    pub fn push_front(&mut self, elem: T) {
        let new_node = Box::new(Node {
            elem: elem,
            next: self.head.take(),
        });

        self.head = Some(new_node);
    }

    pub fn reverse(&mut self) {
        if self.head.is_none() || self.head.as_ref().unwrap().next.is_none() {
            return;
        }

        let mut prev = None;
        let mut current_node = self.head.take();
        while current_node.is_some() {
            let next = current_node.as_mut().unwrap().next.take();
            current_node.as_mut().unwrap().next = prev.take();
            prev = current_node.take();
            current_node = next;
        }

        self.head = prev.take();
    }

    pub fn iter(&self) -> Iter<T> {
        Iter { next: self.head.as_ref().map(|node| &**node) }
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for Iter<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.next.map(|node| {
            self.next = node.next.as_ref().map(|node| &**node);
            &node.elem
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut l = List::new();
    l.push_front(3);
    l.push_front(2);
    l.push_front(1);
    l.push_front(12);

    for item in l.iter() {
        print!("{} ", item);
    }
    println!();
    l.reverse();
    for item in l.iter() {
        print!("{} ", item);
    }
    println!();
}
```

[Link to Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7bdd81e6c3276cd0c7f7cc68f2b4f24e&version=stable&backtrace=2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before I begin, I recommend reading [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/).

1. Avoid `unwrap`s, especially those after checking `is_some`. Use pattern matching instead.
2. The first test in `reverse` is redundant with the rest of the logic.
3. Implement `Debug` or `Display` to DRY up the printing of the list.
4. You should have **some** tests, especially for edge cases: 0, 1, and 2 items.
5. I'm not a fan of side effects inside of a `map` - it should err more on the side of purely functional. I'd use a match, even though it's more lines of code.
6. I'd simplify the iterator by just keeping a `&Link`
7. You could choose to remove the temporary variable from `push_front`.
8. `for item in foo.iter()` is usually written as `for item in &foo`, which implies that you need to implement `IntoIterator` for a reference to your type.

```
use std::fmt;

type Link<T> = Option<Box<Node<T>>>;

struct Node<T> {
    elem: T,
    next: Link<T>,
}

struct List<T> {
    head: Link<T>,
}

pub struct Iter<'a, T: 'a> {
    next: &'a Link<T>,
}

impl<T> List<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        List { head: None }
    }

    pub fn push_front(&mut self, elem: T) {
        self.head = Some(Box::new(Node {
            elem: elem,
            next: self.head.take(),
        }));
    }

    pub fn reverse(&mut self) {
        let mut prev = None;
        let mut current_node = self.head.take();

        while let Some(mut current_node_inner) = current_node.take() {
            let next = current_node_inner.next.take();
            current_node_inner.next = prev.take();
            prev = Some(current_node_inner);
            current_node = next;
        }

        self.head = prev.take();
    }

    pub fn iter(&self) -> Iter<T> {
        Iter { next: &self.head }
    }
}

impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a List<T> {
    type Item = &'a T;
    type IntoIter = Iter<'a, T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.iter()
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for Iter<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        match self.next.as_ref() {
            Some(next) => {
                self.next = &next.next;
                Some(&next.elem)
            }
            None => None,
        }
    }
}

impl<T> fmt::Debug for List<T>
    where T: fmt::Debug,
{
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        for item in self {
            write!(f, "{:?} ", item)?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a thorough reply!! It is definitely much nicer to use pattern matching instead of all the unwraps. It had completely skipped my mind :)